# Is there an error in my IIS7 Rewrite, causing it to add an HTTPS suffice to the url?

Tags: debugging, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I set up up a redirect  to redirect xyzUX.com >   myServer/Subfolder
I thought there might be an error in my IIS7.5 Rewrite Rules. So I removed that part. But I left in an http>https Rewrite.

But I can't see anything in it that would cause the problem.

1. Problem browsing to >  http://claynicholsUX.com gets rewritten to:  https://claynicholsux.comhttps/
2. Result : that *https* suffix causes the page to not be valid (site not found)
3. Desired result: the suffix is not added
   If I start with https://claynicholsux.com  then no rewrite happens.

   ```
                      </conditions>
                   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{PATH_INFO}" />
              </rule>


           </rules>
   ```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do, what is final result, and where is problem?

Comment: @VladoPandžić  I clarified it.